# Loading XML file in MySQL getting extra rows

Tags: mysql, xml

I've run this for other files and have never seen this before and can't tell what is happening.

Here is my table structure:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Searchword; COMMIT;
CREATE TABLE Searchword ( 
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, SearchwordID int 
, ConceptID int 
, Searchword nvarchar(80)
, CreateDate datetime 
, LastDate datetime 
, LanguageID int 
, PRIMARY KEY (id) 
); COMMIT;
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Searchword.xsd" generated="2020-10-09T10:05:52">
    <Searchword>
        <SearchwordID>1</SearchwordID>
        <ConceptID>1</ConceptID>
        <Searchword>Tacos</Searchword>
        <CreateDate>2020-07-15T09:45:34</CreateDate>
        <LastDate>2020-07-15T09:45:34</LastDate>
        <LanguageID>1</LanguageID>
    </Searchword>
    <Searchword>
        <SearchwordID>2</SearchwordID>
        <ConceptID>1</ConceptID>
        <Searchword>Beef Tacos</Searchword>
        <CreateDate>2020-07-15T09:42:50</CreateDate>
        <LastDate>2020-07-15T09:42:50</LastDate>
        <LanguageID>1</LanguageID>
    </Searchword>
    <Searchword>
        <SearchwordID>3</SearchwordID>
        <ConceptID>1</ConceptID>
        <Searchword>Tacos Supreme</Searchword>
        <CreateDate>2020-07-15T09:42:50</CreateDate>
        <LastDate>2020-07-15T09:42:50</LastDate>
        <LanguageID>1</LanguageID>
    </Searchword>
</dataroot>
```

My Load code:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:/filelocation/Searchword.xml' 
INTO TABLE Searchword 
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Searchword>'; 
;COMMIT;
```

But here are my results:

[image: Results]

I can't figure out why the highlighted rows above are appearing?

Using version 8.0.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you have

Searchword twice in your xml see where the ** are

```
**<Searchword>**
    <SearchwordID>1</SearchwordID>
    <ConceptID>1</ConceptID>
    **<Searchword>Tacos</Searchword>**
    <CreateDate>2020-07-15T09:45:34</CreateDate>
    <LastDate>2020-07-15T09:45:34</LastDate>
    <LanguageID>1</LanguageID>
</Searchword>
```

So the oarser thing that is alsao a row

Comment: Grr thanks for giving me the reason. I changed one of those and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just run the same statement without `ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Searchword>';`

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:/filelocation/Searchword.xml' 
INTO TABLE Searchword 
;COMMIT;
```